# Error pages Symfony2 with locale

Tags: php, symfony, locale, symfony-2.3

I'm trying to translate 404 pages on Symfony2, but it's not working. With 500 error pages it works great.

For example, when i try to access the page: /es/not-found it shows the 404 page, but when i access /en/not-found, it gives me the SAME page, although i have translated the error message on my messages-en.yml.

It seems it's always accessing the messages-es.yml file, because i've configured Symfony with this default locale (es).

If i print {{ app.request.locale }} on my Twig template, it doesn't give me anything.

I cleared the cache several times, yes :).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the localization configuration is properly working, you should be able to print the locale on Twig. With something like this:

```
{% if app.request.locale == 'en' %}
    English 404 message
{% else %}
    Other 404 message
{% endif %}
```

*If your Symfony version is less than 2.1 you must use app.session.locale instead of app.request.locale*

Nevertheless is a **good practice** to always create **custom 404** and any other error page you need:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html

The most powerfull way is using this method:

*Replace the default exception controller twig.controller.exception:showAction with your own controller and handle it however you want (see exception_controller in the Twig reference). The default exception controller is registered as a service - the actual class is Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController.*

This way you can even have different templates for each country.

Kind regards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try creating my own controller!

Comment: Yes! Now it works (customizing the controller that handles the exception). Nevertheless it's weird that the controller inside TwigBundle does not handle locales correctly. I'll take a look, probably it's my fault.

Comment: Do you have an example of your own controller?